# $ionicHistory save and restore

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to save the user's app navigation history in local storage and be able to restore it after the user shuts down the app or reboots their device.

I am creating an ionic app that "wizards" a user through about 10 forms. I am saving the data state to localStorage on each change, along with the last page completed.  This way I can restore the user back to the right form with all their saved data if they close the app or restart the phone.

The problem is that when that happens, the history is lost. I see that I can view the $ionicHistory, but how do I save that and restore it back at a future point? I could save output of $ionicHistory.viewHistory() to localStorage, but there does not seems to be a method like .setHistory...

Answer (score 1):

At this time Ionic doesn't support that function. But I think you can save the lasted `URL route` and `form data` to localStorage.

Here is my manually idea:

1. When user re-open the app, you can open up a popup and ask for your user if he wants to come back to the lasted view.
2. The `comfirm` button should have a href link (restore from localStorage) put in it. If user click on Ok the app will automatically navigate to that view.
3. Restore `form data` from localStorage and bind it to the view.

Comment: Yes, your manual idea is similar to what I am doing.  I am presenting a start up page that prompts the user and if they want to restore their saved form, it loads the form data from localStorage and sends them to their last state using $state.go().  The problem is that in doing so, **the navigation in ion-nav in nav bar sends them back to the page asking if they want to restore their saved form.**  If they were on page 6, I want the navigation to go to page 5 (from their last "session") after the restore, not back to the last page of this "session" (the page asking to restore or not).

Comment: If the forms are linear, you can replace back button with button heading to the previous state.

Comment: You can store all the navigation history into array nested object and put id in it. Then check the back button event and do some process to test the current id with next/previous id and load that view.